# Help with Dropdowns/ChoiceMenus

Tags: forms

I have a simple dropdown/choice menu right now, but is there any way to customize it? I am very new to coding so there is a lot of simple stuff I'm still having trouble with right now, but is there any way to make the choice menu box bigger or change the color? And would it be possible to make 4 or 5 of the dropdown/choice menus across a page horizontally? Thanks

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{Form}


    \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 1,name=box1,
    ]{}
    {Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}


    \end{Form}
    \end{document}
```

EDIT: Thanks to the first answer, very helpful. I need help with changing size/heigh/width/color of the individual choices like Item 1, Item 2, etc. if anybody knows how to do that. I also need help with drawing lines between the different main boxes (Box1, Box2, etc.). Again, I'm very new to this so I'm sure drawing a line in the right place is simple, but the positioning and putting it in the right place (between the boxes) is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 6):

To modify the height, you can manipulate the `DefaultHeightofChoiceMenue`. For more parameter to adjust see the `hyperef` manual or the nice webpage  http://dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/eforms.shtml#gls:DefaultHeightofChoiceMenu1

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofChoiceMenu}{20ex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}

        \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 1,name=box1]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}
        \quad % adds a bit of space
        \ChoiceMenu[print,combo,default=Box 2,name=box2]{}{Item 1,Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5}

    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks! If anybody knows how to do color or the height/width/color of the answer choices (Item 1, Item 2, etc.) that would be great also. Again, @samcarter thanks for the answer!